# How to validate email in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, email-validation

I have written the following contact form validation script. How can I validate a email field?

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.contactForm { width:370px; margin:0 auto; }
    form.contactUs label { display:block; }
    form.contactUs input { margin-bottom:10px; }
    input.submit { margin-top:10px; }
    input.error { background:#FF9B9B; border:1px solid red; }
    div.errorMessage { color:#f00; padding:0 0 20px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.errorMessage').hide();
        $('.submit').click(function() {

            var name = $('input.name').val();
            var email = $('input.email').val();
            var phone = $('input.phone').val();

            if (name == '') {
                $('input.name').addClass('error');
                $('input.name').keypress(function(){
                    $('input.name').removeClass('error');
                });
            }
            if (email == '') {
                $('input.email').addClass('error');
                $('input.email').keypress(function(){
                    $('input.email').removeClass('error');
                });
            }
            if (phone == '') {
                $('input.phone').addClass('error');
                $('input.phone').keypress(function(){
                    $('input.phone').removeClass('error');
                });
            }
            if (name == '' || email == '' || phone == '') {
                $('.errorMessage').fadeIn('medium');
                return false;
            }

        });
    });
</script>

<div class="contactForm">

<h2>Contact Us</h2>

<div class="errorMessage">Please enter all required fields.</div>

<form action="http://google.com" method="post" class="contactUs">

    <label>Name <em>(required)</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="name" size="30" />

    <label>Email <em>(valid email required)</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="email" size="30" />

    <label>Phone <em>(required)</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone" size="30" />

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />

</form>

</div><!--contactForm-->
```

### EDIT

By validation I mean the entered value must contain a " @ " and a " . " at proper place.

Also I don't want to use any additional plugins.

Comment: First, what do you define email validation to be?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use RegEx if you don't want to use any plugins.

```
var testEmail = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
if (testEmail.test(valueToTest))
    // Do whatever if it passes.
else
    // Do whatever if it fails.
```

This will get you most emails. An interesting read about [validating emails with RegEx.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

You can test the script here: http://jsfiddle.net/EFfCa/

Comment: No it doesn't.  It invalidates perfectly valid, working emails.  Please don't use this.

Comment: See the link Randal, you have to decide at what point you call valid because you'd end up with a huge RegEx statement otherwise. As the poster said, he doesn't want to use plugins.

Comment: must to be upgraded for new domain zones
for example for .university or .engineer

Comment: the domain length should be changed since the max length of 4 is no longer valid. Use this : {2,} instead of {2,4}

jsfillde: http://jsfiddle.net/ch3rf1vq/

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to use a plugin I've found this method to be quite good:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thejimgaudet/kmvgw/)

http://thejimgaudet.com/articles/support/web/jquery-e-mail-validation-without-a-plugin/

Comment: This allows blank fields to be validated as correct!

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using [ketchup](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/) for form validation. There's also [bassassist's plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Check a plugin, it will save you hours of regex-writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `input.email` block as this:

```
            if (email == '') {
            $('input.email').addClass('error');
            $('input.email').keypress(function(){
                $('input.email').removeClass('error');
            });
            $('input.email').focusout(function(){
                $('input.email').filter(function(){
                    return this.value.match(/your email regex/);
                }).addClass('error');
            });
        }
```

Explaination:
Add focusout action to `input.email` form element, validates the email string using RFC822 standard. If it can't pass then add the 'error' class.

I have not tested this on my browser but it should work for jQuery > 1.4.

EDIT: I've removed the regex, place your favorite one there.

Comment: Please don't use this regex. It invalidates perfect valid, in-use emails.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working for me.

```
<input type="text" id="Email" />

$('#Email').change(function () {
        var status = false;
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var emailLength = email.length;
        if (email != "" && emailLength > 4) {
            email = email.replace(/\s/g, "");  //To remove space if available
            var dotIndex = email.indexOf(".");
            var atIndex = email.indexOf("@");

            if (dotIndex > -1 && atIndex > -1) {   //To check (.) and (@) present in the string
                if (dotIndex != 0 && dotIndex != emailLength && atIndex != 0 && atIndex != emailLength && email.slice(email.length - 1) != ".") {   //To check (.) and (@) are not the firat or last character of string
                    var dotCount = email.split('.').length
                    var atCount = email.split('@').length

                    if (atCount == 2 && (dotIndex - atIndex > 1)) { //To check (@) present multiple times or not in the string. And (.) and (@) not located subsequently
                        status = true;
                        if (dotCount > 2) {    //To check (.) are not located subsequently
                            for (i = 2; i <= dotCount - 1; i++) {
                                if (email.split('.')[i-1].length == 0) {
                                    status = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        $('#Email').val(email);
        if (!status) {
            alert("Wrong Email Format");
        }
    });
```