# jquery email validation [sorted]

Tags: jquery, email-validation

my code: http://jsfiddle.net/umSFC/

i follow [How to validate email in Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663968/how-to-validate-email-in-jquery) for email validation but seem dont work on mine?

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html <-- here's a very concise RegExp you could use...? :P

Answer (score 0):

Use j[Query Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Has an [email](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email) validator for what you want and is better to use a consistent validation throughout your application and forms. On other hand is better to use tested components and whenever possible use existing works and not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229259/jquery-pitfalls-to-avoid/1238258#1238258, but as you can see validate is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Here i have fixed your exsample](http://jsfiddle.net/umSFC/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function(e) {

        var name = $("#name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var emailaddressVal = $("#email").val();
        var emailReg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;


        if (name.val() == "") {
            name.addClass("error").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            name.removeClass("error");
        }

        if (!emailReg.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("error").focus();

        } else {

            email.removeClass("error");
        }



        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```